# Removing POST data so back button won't display Document Expired

Tags: php, forms, session, caching, post

When my page does a post, I store all the `$_POST` data in a separate `$_SESSION` var. I know that a back button to this same page is by design to show the `Document Expired` message. My hope is to fool the browser into thinking that there was really never any `$_POST` data and so not to display the `Document Expired` message when coming back to it. I am forcing a complete refresh of the page so I am not worried about receiving old data, since I have it stored in the session.

I have tried to `unset($_POST)` hoping this will stay with the page. but the `$_POST` data must be cached / stored and returns with a refresh or back button. Is what I am trying to do possible? Any ideas?

*** UPDATE ***
My solution / answer is posted below. It posts to a separate form, which redirects back to the original form for processing. Not sure why the down vote. It has been working great for months and I no longer receive Document Expired messages. It also prevents duplicate posting.

Comment: How are you doing this refresh exactly? Add some code.

Comment: use a post-redirect-get instead.

Comment: For starters, I have window.onbeforeunload defined and I am under the impression from [here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript) that if forces a complete refresh. I can also set header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'); header('Pragma: no-cache'); if necessary

Comment: `$_POST` is on the server; your issue is that the _browser_ still has it in its history

Comment: Of course... Then this would be a dead end, since I won't be able to modify the browser's history. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Just two things: maybe you could use `header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` to go back, then you wouldn't need to pass the current page through the `action`; and, keep in mind that you might not always want to go back to the same page you came.

Comment: You should post that as your own answer and accept it, instead of putting the answer inside the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** UPDATE ***
Here's my solution.

I am aware that with post-redirect-get the POST is usually back to the same page for processing before being redirected away from the form with a GET to another destination. However, I need to be able to return to the original page for re-editing (as in a document model where the user can SAVE work in progress). Therefore doing the POST to a second page and redirecting back to the original was my idea of getting rid of the "EXPIRED" message since the editing form would not have post data associated with it. I have extended this (not shown) to include $_FILE and other situations (e.g. using it with `a href` as well). Not sure why the downvote. This has been working great for months now and accomplishes the task. I no longer receive "Document Expired" messages. In addition, all $_POST processing is accomplished in the original file.

testform.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET) && count($_GET)>0){
    // process get
    var_dump($_GET);
}
if (isset($_SESSION['post-copy'])){
    // return post vars to $_POST variable so can process as normal
    $_POST = $_SESSION['post-copy'];

    // unset the session var - with refresh can't double process
    unset($_SESSION['post-copy']);

    // process post vars
    var_dump($_POST);
}

?>

<form method='post' action='__b.php?redirect=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>&help=me' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <textarea name='descr' id='descr'>ABCD</textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
```

redirect.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_POST)){
    $_SESSION['post-copy'] = $_POST;
}

// retrieve the url to return to
if (isset($_GET['redirect'])){
    $url = $_GET['redirect'];
}

// if multiple query string parameters passed in get, isolate the redirect so can build querystring with the rest
if (isset($_GET) && count($_GET) > 1){
    $get = $_GET;        
    foreach ($get as $key => $val){
        if ($key == 'redirect'){
            // remove from rest of passed get query string
            unset($get[$key]);
        }            
    }
    if (count($get) > 0){
        $url .= (strpos($url,"?")===false ? "?" : "&") . http_build_query($get);
    }

}

if ($url!==""){
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

Comment: I completed my answer with some code to show how to keep all form related code in one place.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using the post - redirect - get design pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

A more standard way to implement this pattern is to display, validate and save the form on one page.

The following solution has these advantages :
1. All form related code is in one place. 
2. Server side validation is simple

I have two pages, form.php and after.php.

form.php :

```
if(isPosted()){
    if(dataIsValid($postedData)){ 
// dataIsValid should set $message to show to the user
        saveData($postedData);
        redirect('after.php');
        die();
    }
} else {
    $postedData = $defaultValues;
}
showForm($postedData, $message);
```

Comment: I understand this is how many prefer to deal with it. It adds an extra layer I would prefer to avoid. It ends up being two pages I have to maintain instead of one for every circumstance. Perhaps if I could develop a completely generic PRG page that would work for multiple situations that automatically saved the $_POST data and then redirected... (By the way I am not the one who down-voted you.)

Comment: @mseifert, that's what i do. I have a unique page where all the post go to, get the return, and redirects to the initial page.

Comment: See my updated php solution. I appreciate the encouragement to go this route.

Comment: To clarify - "save & stay on editing page" is the option I need without producing Document Expired. Redirect after edit is not the desired action from the editing standpoint. I was hoping the redirect before processing would get rid of the "Expired" message sine the editing page would not have post data.

Comment: When the form validation passes, there is a redirect, so there is no issue. When validation fails, there can be a problem.

Comment: Under what conditions does the browser gives the "Expired" message and which pages does the browser keep in history? My understanding is that once a POST is made to a page, it cannot be navigated back to without the message. Redirecting away from the POST page was my idea to prevent it having POST data. Your solution POSTs to the original page. If I navigate back to it, wouldn't I get the EXPIRED message? Does a redirect prevent navigation back to the original page through redirecting again or does the Browser not keep it in history?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to the beginning of your script to solve this issue.

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=300, must-revalidate");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that comes to mind?  Don't directly do the post, catch the event and submit the form through AJAX.  Then on success, redirect.

An example using jQuery:

```
$('#some_form').submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function() {
       window.location = "/some/success/url.php";
    });
    return false; // Prevent the form submission & any other events triggered on submit
});
```

Because the POST never got added to the browser history, you won't have that issue.

**However**, note that the POST url is now different than the one you load; you can make it the same by checking whether a POST or a GET was done server-side, but either way, you have to do a bit of extra work to "remember" the results of the POST.

Comment: I posted above a pure php solution that is simple enough without going to AJAX (which I don't currently use). I appreciate the input. In the end, it got me where I needed to go.